# Duda sobre una consulta SELECT y cláusula UNION en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

El asunto es así: tengo una tabla con una lista de jugadores identificados con un único id:

tabla jugadores:

| jugador_id | Nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Carlos |
| 2 | Pedro |
| 3 | Antonio |
| 4 | Federico |

y tengo otra con resultados que muestran los partidos que ganaron cuando dos de estos jugadores jugaron juntos:

tabla resultados:

| jugador1 | Jugador2 | partidos_ganados |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 |

quiero obtener como resultado, cuanto partidos ganó cada jugador, ordenados desde quien ganó mas a menos. No me doy cuenta como debo hacerla, muchas gracias a quienes me ayuden en esto

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aunque sea probaste algo????

Comment: Leí e intenté seguir los consejos. Soy principiante y la puse esfuerzo a la pregunta. Perdón si no está bien fundamentada, quizás en proximas preguntas aprenderé la mejor manera de efectuarlas

Comment: Probaste alguna consulta? para resolver esto hay que hacer uso de varias cosas, por eso pregunto.. una cosa es guiarte.. otra darte directamente la solucion, que nunca es la idea...

Comment: Si, claro que probé. Pero entendí que publicando lo que estaba haciendo, solo iba a generar confusión y me concentré en redactar la pregunta de la manera mas clara posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select j.nombre, sum(t.ganados) as ganados from
((select jugador1 as jugador, sum(partidos_ganados) as ganados
from resultados 
group by jugador1)
union
(select jugador2 as jugador, sum(partidos_ganados) as ganados
from resultados
group by jugador2)) t 
inner join jugadores j
on t.jugador = j.jugador_id
group by j.nombre
order by sum(t.ganados) desc
```

Esta consulta sql se divide en varias partes y debes analizar desde la consulta más interna hasta llegar a la más externa.

Primero se hace una consulta para obtener el total de juegos ganados por el **campo jugador1**. Se hace también una consulta idéntica pero para obtener el total de juegos ganados por el **campo jugador2**. En ambas consultas se usa la **cláusula group by** que permite agrupar datos con un mismo valor y la **función de agregación sum**, la cual suma los juegos ganados por cada jugador.

Estas dos consultas se unen usando el **operador de conjuntos union** el cual une los registros devueltos por ambas consultas de forma que esos dos conjuntos de registros se unan en un solo conjunto de registros.

Sobre esta consulta más interna hacemos una consulta externa, la cual incluirá la **cláusula inner join** juntando los registros devueltos en la consulta interna con la **tabla jugadores** a través de un campo en común para obtener el nombre de los jugadores, usamos igualmente la **cláusula group by** para agrupar por los nombres de los jugadores, obtenido de esta forma los partidos ganados de cada jugador, por último se utiliza la **cláusula order by** para ordenar los registros obtenidos por el total de juegos ganados de manera descendente.

Comment: No ha sido una respuesta, ha sido un excelente tutorial sobre el uso de la cláusula UNION. Muchas gracias, es lo que necesitaba

Comment: @ClaudioO y no votamos positivo ni aceptamos la respuesta porque......

Comment: Yo voté positivo pero me salió un aviso que aun no se registraba mi voto porque soy novato (o algo así) Con respecto a aceptar la respuesta no sé cómo hacerlo, me podrías indicar?

Comment: @ClaudioO para aceptar una respuesta lo unico que debes hacer es dar click sobre el check que sale junto con los botones para votar una pregunta. Revisa este link para mas informacion https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Gracias, ya lo hice. Además corregí el enunciado de la pregunta para que sea más específica y pueda servirle a otro con una duda similar. Ya voy aprendiendo